# mysql select distinct months (abbreviation) from table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I am trying to see what months are used in my table. I can get id and name (see below) no problem but I am having trouble pulling out the abrv. I have done it before using %b but can't seem to get the syntax right here. Where am I going wrong?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(date) as id, 
    MONTHNAME(date) as name, 
    MONTHNAME(date, '%b') as abrv
    FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC
```

I want to return

```
    id  |name       |abrv
    1   |January    |Jan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(date) as id, 
    MONTHNAME(date) as name, 
    SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(date),1,3) as abrv
    FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: when I do SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(date),0,3) I get nothing but when I change it to SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(date),1,3) it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `date_format` function, not `monthname`:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(date) as id, 
    MONTHNAME(date) as name, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b') as abrv
    FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC
```